# How do I configure this views properly with ui-router in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to modify an existing **AngularJS** application that uses **ui-router**. The routing table is pretty big and even though I can make it work, I don't understand why.

The states are configured using "Object-based" states, and they look like:

```
parent = {
    abstract: true,
    name: 'parent',
    views: {
        'key': {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/parent.html'
        }
    }
},
child = {
    name: 'parent.child',
    views: {
        'other-key': {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/child.html'
        }
    }
},
```

The dot syntax is used to infer the hierarchy. Regarding the views, parent.html contains some html and a reference to child.html like:

```
<div data-ui-view="other-key"></div>
```

And, it works!. As far as I understand, when child is activated, the parent and abstract state (that can't be activated) is used to inherit the data. That makes me think that I should be able to put these two views in the same state, and they should work.

However, I have two scenarios:

- If I move them to the parent state only the parent view is rendered, and ui-router seems to be unable to load child.
- If I move them to the child state nothing gets rendered.

**Seems reasonable to think that everything should work exactly in the same way if they are inside, together, of the views collection of the same state**:

```
child = {
    name: 'parent.child',
    views: {
        'key': {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/parent.html'
        }
        'other-key': {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/child.html'
        }
    }
},
```

When the state is activated all the information is available to compute the state, but somehow it does not work.

Hope I'm including all the information. The routing table is too big to be pasted here.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "I should be able to put these two views in the same state, and they should work". Can you expand more on what you are trying? Are you trying to merge the two states into one?

Comment: post code snippet you tried which doesnt work like you want. This 2 states seems to be ok.

Comment: Thanks! I added the state as I would like it to work (or at least, understand why it does not work). In the child state you can find the key for both views. Other option that did not work was having the two views but in the parent state as opposed to the child.

I understand that the only state that really exists is child as the other is abstract and cannot be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with both scenarios are slightly different, so I'll tackle them separately.

## Moving everything up to the parent state

In this case, you can't render the child template because it is inside the parent view. Hence, when ui-router's resolving your state it can only locate one named view (the parent) and thus it's the only one that will be rendered.

## Moving everything down to the child state

The issue here is pretty much the same as in the first case, however nothing is getting rendered now because the child state can't locate the parent state. You could fix this by [absolutely referencing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) the parent's named view:

```
'key@parent': '/app/views/parent.html'
```

I'm not entirely sure, but my guess is this still won't suffice to render both views (I believe only the parent will be rendered and hence you'll end up in exactly the same situation as if you would have moved both to the parent).

## The solution

Pretty straight forward, put both named views on the same level and it will work or keep them in separate states to allow the child state to resolve its named view from the parent's template.

Comment: First and foremost @Anzeo, thank you very much. Can you explain f.e "the child state can't locate the parent state"?.

I thought that at one specific moment only one state was active, but you express it as if one the states should locate the other. I thought than when child was activated, only child was active but it contained the information from the parent state.

Also, regarding the views, isn't the same state when rendering the parent view and when rendering the child? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: It's true that at any given time, there's only one state that will be the "current state", however all parent states of the current state will be active as well. Concerning rendering the states, no, it isn't the same. In the first case you'll render from the parent state and so the parent view can be resolved, in the second case you'll render from the child state and hence the parent's view can't be resolved from there (it is only known on the level of the parent)